# vb 2015 GDI+ bitmap placement

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, panel, gdi+

I've had little luck trying to find the answer to this either on stackoverflow specifically, or on the internet in general.

I have a form in a vb 2015 Windows Forms project.

On that form, I've placed six controls: four textboxes, a panel, and a button.

When I click the button, it generates a bitmap, like so:

```
 Private Sub btnSetLeft_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSetLeft.Click
    Dim R As Integer = CInt(txtRedLeft.Text)
    Dim G As Integer = CInt(txtGreenLeft.Text)
    Dim B As Integer = CInt(txtBlueLeft.Text)
    Dim A As Integer = CInt(txtAlphaLeft.Text)
    gcL = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B)
    Using bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(9, 9)
        Using gBM As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            Using br As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(gcL)
                gBM.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 0, 8, 8))
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
 End Sub
```

But, after building the bitmap, I want the button to place the bitmap on the panel and then repaint the panel, thus displaying the new bitmap.

How do I do that?

Comment: `thePanel.BackgroundImage = bm`  you will have to remove it from the USING block so you dont dispose of it, and that means if you click again you should dispose of the old one (or reuse the same one)

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard (I simplified your example):

```
Dim gcL As Color = Color.Blue
Using bm As New Bitmap(9, 9)
    Using gBM As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
        Using br As New SolidBrush(gcL)
            gBM.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 0, 8, 8))
        End Using
    End Using
    panel1.BackgroundImage = bm
    panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile
    panel1.Update()
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you - The panel is significantly larger than the bitmap, and I don't want to use it as the panel's background image. Instead, I want to be able to place the bitmap at some specified position on the panel.

Comment: You could have two bitmaps.   One will fill the panel.  You can 'draw' your smaller bitmap anywhere on the larger bitmap.

Comment: If there's no way to put it directly on the panel, I suppose I could do that. But, somehow, placing it directly on the panel seems more elegant. (sigh) What would the code look like to draw the smaller bitmap on the larger one?

Comment: You can also override the control's OnPaint message but I think that is more complicated.   Use Google to find the techniques.